# Overstayed on Visa Waiver Program and I am planning another holiday?

Tags: us-visa-waiver-program, esta, b1-b2-visas

I went on the Visa Waiver Program to Chicago 3 years ago, I ended up over staying by 2 days. I am now going back for a week long holiday and I am just wondering what I need this time to allow me into country with no hassle? I am travelling from Ireland.

Comment: @neubert how on earth is it a duplicate of that one?? One's about the 90 day rule, the other is about trying to come back after overstaying!